# Were all the main events/places in the Harry Potter universe set in Britain/UK?

Tags: harry-potter

For example, the [Ministry of Magic](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/British_Ministry_of_Magic) is in London. [Azkaban](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Azkaban) is in the North Sea. [Hogwarts](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogwarts_School_of_Witchcraft_and_Wizardry) is in Scotland.

All the main characters seems to be distinctly British. Passing references are made to the Muggle Prime Minister (presumably the UK PM).

So, were all the main events/places in the Harry Potter universe set entirely in Britain/UK?

---

Gaius points out, I believe correctly, that there were some French and German sports teams at the tournament. There are also passing references to potions and beasts from exotic far away lands and foreign magical academies. But if I recall correctly nothing of note ever seems to takes place in "foreign" lands.

Comment: Aren't there French and German magic schools at the sports tournament?

Comment: @Gaius: Oh OK. You're probably right, I probably forgot that. Let me rephrase my question a little then.

Comment: The out-of-universe explanation would be that before HP made her a billionaire, JKR had probably not traveled much

Comment: Kenny LJ, have you even read the books?

Comment: @JamesfromNZ: Yea, but some years ago. I was just watching the last few movies and the above question occurred to me.

Comment: @KennyLJ So you are asking from cinematic perspective or from in-universe book explanations? Movies are sometimes **loosely connected** to the books. In the books series wizard communities from Ireland, France, Bulgaria, Albania, Greece, Ancient Egypt were mentioned, not to mention Fantastic Beasts movies -which are considered canon, as they are written by JK herself- which are set in USA.

Comment: Question: where might a story about a british school kid and his adventures take place?

Comment: @Gaius - She'd certainly been to France at least

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Books

The overwhelming majority of the events that are happening contemporaneously in the main book series take place within the confines of the United Kingdom. **The sole exception seems to be Voldemort's hunt for the Elder wand. Harry sees the search for Gregorovich and his attack on Grindlewald (at his prison in Nurmengard)** through Voldermort's eyes *in realtime*.

> He approached one of them, then saw the whiteness of his own long-fingered hand against the door. He knocked. He felt a mounting excitement …
>   The door opened: a laughing woman stood there. Her face fell as she looked into Harry’s face, humour gone, terror replacing it …
>   ‘Gregorovitch?’ said a high, cold voice.
>   She shook her head: she was trying to close the door. A white hand held it steady, prevented her shutting him out …
>   ‘I want Gregorovitch.’
>   ‘*Er wohnt hier nicht mehr!*’ she cried, shaking her head. ‘He no live here! He no live here! I know him not!’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12 (Magic is Might)</sup></sub>

and

> “Kill me, then!’ demanded the old man. ‘You will not win, you cannot win! That wand will never, ever be yours –’
>   And Voldemort’s fury broke: a burst of green light filled the prison room and the frail old body was lifted from its hard bed and then fell back, lifeless, and Voldemort returned to the window, his wrath barely controllable … they would suffer his retribution if they had no good reason for calling him back …”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)</sup></sub>

---

There are a considerable number of other *events* that take place outside the UK, for example arrivals of students from overseas for the Tri-Wizard cup, Hermione's holiday to France, the arrival of Quidditch teams from around the world for the World Cup, Voldemort attacking Prof. Quirrel in Albania, Hermione's parents traveling to Australia, The Weasley family traveling to Egypt, etc **but all of these take place in retrospect or are recounted via a third-party to the reader or are told to people in the story.**

### Films

All of the events of the original film series take place in the UK (with the exception of the "flashback" events recounted above) however the first film of the *Fantastic Beasts* series of films takes place entirely in ***America***. The next film is apparently going to be based in Paris.

Comment: There's also Voldemort's trip to Germany to try and trace Gregorovitch earlier in the same book.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - See edit. I think this is as close as we're going to get. For the record, I've discounted the breakout from Azkaban since we don't know its actual location other than "in the north sea".

Comment: was Gregorovitch / Nurmengard ever stated to be in Germany? Sure, the lady speaks German, but that's not necessarily conclusive

Comment: @NKCampbell - "*The buildings on either side of him had high, timbered gables; they looked like gingerbread houses.*" - They don't generally make houses like that in the UK

Comment: I don't disagree that it wasn't in the UK, but Germany has come up in the comments (well...I think one reference to Germany was linking Durmstrang) anyway - just thinking that "Germany" is never really stated specifically for either Nurmengard or Durmstrang.

Comment: @NKCampbell - There's no specific confirmation of Germany in the book for Gregorovich, nor is a specific location given for Nurmengard in any source that I've come across. It's all just vaguely German/Austrian.

Comment: exactly - just pointing that out for folks